# String interpolation: apply multiple times at once

Tags: c#, string-formatting, .net-4.5, string-interpolation

I have an string interpolation like below:

```
$"{PREFIX}{Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar}{Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar}{Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar}{SUFIX}"
```

Is there any way to avoid repeating the same **{Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar}** several times?

Comment: `$"{PREFIX}{new string(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, 3)}{SUFFIX}"`?  or `string.Join(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, PREFIX, string.Empty, string.Empty, SUFFIX);`

Comment: The first one works because it's a single `char`, if you needed to repeat a string of characters then the second one would be the way to go.

Comment: @juharr thx for the clarification.